# Mysql single column table --> insert in other table

Tags: mysql, import

I have two tables: `t1` and `t2`
- `t2` has only 1 column named `stuff` (60.000 entries). 
- `t1` has 15 columns, including `stuff` (empty). `t1` has about 650.000 entries.

How can I import the data from `t2.stuff` in `t1.stuff` when I have nothing to match it against? (I just want to populate empty fields of `t1.stuff` with data from `t2.stuff` and don't care about matching ids or anything.)

The best case (i think) would be, that if I run this query about 11 times, all fields of `t1.stuff` would be populated, because no empty field in `t1.stuff` is left over.

Here is an example what the tables look like:

`t1`: 
`|__a___|_b_|_c_|stuff|...|`
`|___308|foo|bar|_____|baz|`
`|___312|foo|bar|_____|baz|`
...
`|655578|foo|bar|_____|baz|`

`t2`: 
`|___stuff___|`
`|some_info_1|`
`|some_info_2|`
...
`|some_info_n|`

Maybe there are multiple steps required...

***UPDATE***

Here is the ***SOLUTION*** I went with in case someone has a similar problem - All credits go to user **nurdglaw** for pointing me in the right direction. So here we go:

1. Add a new column to your table in question populated with autoincrementing numbers (I set `alter table t1 auto_increment = 1` and temporary disabled autoincrementing on my primary key, to avoid an error with this code) `ALTER TABLE t1 ADD COLUMN new_column INTEGER UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT;`
2. Did the same thing for t2. If you don't already have a second table, you can do something like this: 
   `CREATE TABLE t2 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,t2_data_column VARCHAR(255));` <-- adjust number to your needs
   and import your data with: 
   `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path_on_your_server/data_file.csv'` 
   `INTO TABLE t2` 
   `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'` <-- adjust to your linebreak needs 
   `(t2_data_column)`
3. Now that you have something to match against, you can `INNER JOIN` `t1` with `t2` by doing the following: Add the data from `t2` to `t1`
   `UPDATE t1 AS s` 
   `JOIN t2 AS t ON t.id=s.new_column` 
   `SET s.stuff=t.t2_data_column;` <-- `stuff` was the column in `t1` I wanted to import the data to.
4. Tidy up the mess
   `DROP TABLE t2;` 
   `ALTER TABLE t1 DROP COLUMN new_column;` 
   Enable autoincrement on your primary key again and set it to the number you need for new rows, if you used one before.

That is it, you're done!

One further note: I decided to adjust my data offline and import the 650.000 entries needed with this method in one go, rather than doing it with only the 60.000 I put in the initial question. But you'll get the idea of doing it with any number of data and match it with whatever you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INSERT statements create new rows in your table.
You need an UPDATE on the already existing rows

An easy way to do that is using an extern scripting language

; here is a rebol example

; assumming you use the mysql library from softinnov

; and **a_** is the name of the unique key to a row in t1

> db: open mysql://user:pass@mysql
>
> insert db {select * from t1}
>
> t1rows: copy db
>
> insert db {select * from t2}
>
> t2rows: copy db
>
> foreach row t1rows [
>
> > insert db [ {update t1 set t1.stuff = ? where t1.**a_** =  ?} t2rows/1/1  row/1]
> >
> > either tail? next t2rows [
> >
> > > ```
> > >   t2rows: head t2rows
> > > ```
> >
> > ] [
> >
> > > ```
> > >   t2rows: next t2rows
> > > ```
> > >
> > > ]
>
> ]

sorry, I still have difficulties with the formatting and the variables in your example

Comment: Puh, I really tried to understand your answer, but I can't quite follow (I know I'm a noob, mainly used phpmyadmin for database manipulation until now...). What do you mean by the unique key to a row in t1? If you mean the primary key in each row, its autoincrementing numbers like the ones I put in column `a`. (The underlines are representing "nothing" (white space) in the graphic). These values are not simply starting with `1`, `2`and so on, because lots of rows needed to be removed from time to time. `t2`does not have something like this. `t2` data contains pure text imported from csv file.

Comment: yes, the primary key is a unique key, so you can use a in the above statement instead of a__ to get a hold for each single row

Comment: you can probably achieve your wish too with pure mysql using cursors and set operations, but I think this will be harder to get

Comment: As you can see in my updated post, I used another method but I believe this could also work, so I accept your answer, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     INSERT INTO t1 (stuff)
     SELECT DISTINCT stuff FROM t2
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately this gives me: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS SELECT stuff FROM t2' at line 2`

Comment: hmm, now i get: `#1062 - Duplicate entry '' for key 'vkey'`

Comment: It seems like the code above creates one new line in `t1` with `some_info_1` from `t2` in it and then fails.

Comment: Thank you, but the same error still occurs: #1062 (like above)